# Binding custom functions to DOM events in prototype?

Tags: javascript, dom, prototypejs

Jquery has a great language construct that looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        alert("Hello world!");
    });
});
```

As you might guess this, once the document has loaded, binds a custom function to the onClick event of all ***a*** tags.

The question is, how can I achieve this same kind of behavior in Prototype?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prototype 1.6 provides the [`dom:loaded`](http://prototypejs.org/api/document/observe) event on document:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    $$('a').each(function(elem) {
        elem.observe("click", function() { alert("Hello World"); });
    });
});
```

I also use the [`each`](http://prototypejs.org/api/enumerable/each) iterator on the array returned by [`$$()`](http://prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar-dollar).

Comment: Nice :) Seems Prototype has learned some new tricks since I last used it!

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).observe('dom:loaded', function() {
    $$('a').invoke('observe', 'click', function() {
        alert('Hello world!');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() { 
     Event.observe(element, 'click', function() { 
         alert("Hello World!");
     });
});
```

Of course you need to "select" the elements first in Prototype.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "selecting the elements first"? Can I do this? `Event.observe($$('a'), 'click', function(){ alert('Hello World!'); });`

Comment: @Mark Biek `Event.on(document, 'click', 'a.greeter_class[rel]', function(event, elt) { alert("Hello " + elt.readAttribute('rel')); event.stop(); });`

Comment: FYI this is Prototype 1.7 syntax which is still in beta