# undefined variable javascript - lightbox

Tags: javascript, lightbox, undefined, lytebox

im trying to open a lightbox when webpages loads  using the javascript library ["lytebox"](http://dolem.com/lytebox/index.php?tab=2)

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="lytebox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lytebox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script>
    function ShowIntro()
    {
        $lb.launch('example.jpg','showPrint:true','Orion Nebula','This is my description, which is optional');
    }
</script>

</head>


<body onLoad="ShowIntro()">
</body>
</html>
```

the code works fine on firefox and chrome, but on internet explorer 8 it doesn't works and I get the following error:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Sat, 24 Sep 2011 05:10:04 UTC


Message: '$lb' is undefined
Line: 12
Char: 3
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/lytebox_v5.1/lytebox.html
```

How can I fix it?

p.s. im using lytebox because it doesnt need jquery, and i dont want cause conflicts with other parts on my page (like "videolightbox")

Answer (score 2):

Here's a guess: Lytebox uses `window.onload` itself in order to set up the `$lb` variable (you can see this at the very end of [the script](http://dolem.com/lib/lytebox/lytebox.js)), and when you do `<body onload"...">` you're basically clobbering Lytebox's `window.onload` function before it has a chance to fire. Here's [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917341/window-onload-and-body-onload-in-ie) that seems to confirm this behavior in IE.

So, how do you add an `onload` event when Lytebox needs its own? Simon Willison actually came up with a solution seven years ago in [a rather classic article](http://simonwillison.net/2004/may/26/addloadevent/). In your case his advice is straightforward to implement:

```
<body><!-- no onload --->
  <script>
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = ShowIntro;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      ShowIntro();
    }
  }
  </script>
</body>
```