# window.onload vs. body.onload vs. document.onready

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between `window.onload`, `document.onready` and `body.onload` ?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191157/window-onload-vs-body-onload) will help you... Best of luck! :)

Comment: Why was this marked as a duplicate? This doesn't even mention jQuery, while the other has it in the title (`ready` is jQuery only).

Comment: Aggree with Ciro.  Far too many people on StackOverflow think that JavaScript === jQuery.

Comment: Fully agree with you guys. Voting to reopen the question.

Comment: Probably because having jQuery wrapped around it makes no difference to what the different events mean.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`window.onload` will wait until all assets have finished downloading, such as images and scripts.

DOM ready waits until you can access the DOM via the API.

As a side note, in this day and age, you ought to be using `window.addEventListener('load', function() { }, false)` or `attachEvent()` for older IEs.

Comment: I think the DOM ready functionality of jQuery would also wait for scripts to load before firing wouldn't it?

Comment: But it cannot work for Chrome, Safari and Opera. Is there an alternative of `window.onload` for those browsers?

Comment: @william: `window.addEventListener('load', function() { }, false)`.

Comment: Yes. `DOMContentLoaded` event from memory.

Comment: What you mean by "in this day and age" is that it should be acceptable to defer script execution to onload on IE8 (since IE6-7 are more or less a thing of the past)?

Comment: @CamiloMartin I mean use the event handler systems besides `onevent` properties.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist document.readyState and DOMContentLoaded are native to JavaScript

Comment: Note that this won't let you know when the contents of an iFrame have loaded :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572734/load-event-not-firing-when-iframe-is-loaded-in-chrome