# Twitter widget conflicting with jquery ui accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter, widget

I have the following code:

```
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>

<script>

new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 4,
  interval: 30000,
  width: 250,
  height: 350,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#5785BC',
      color: '#eff4fa',
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      color: '#424242',
      links: '#2480bd'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: false,
    live: false,
    behavior: 'all'
  }
}).render().setUser('Sometwitterpage').start();

</script>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
#twtr-widget-1 {float:right; border:solid 10px #e6edf5; }

</style>
```

It is on the same page as the jquery UI accordion, for some reason it stops the accordion from working. I have spent quite a few hours seeing what broke the accordion. The accordion only breaks when http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js  is included. The file is compressed so I am not sure where to start. has anyone else come across this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code for accordion here.
  });
  // Code for twitter here.

</script>
```

It works like this but is there any way I can see the source - have you got an url you can share? Then we could work out better where to place the relevant code...

******UPDATE******

I'm updating here as this post is getting a bit messy, what with chat not working etc. So, in an effort to 'contain' the info..

There's no `$(document).ready(function(){})` in the `<head>` you posted to jsfiddle, so you could try to call the twitter widget from...

```
<body onload="new TWTR.Widget({}).render().setUser('Sometwitterpage').start();">
```

- it may be better to write a function that you can call from onload and that function contains the call for new twitter widget.
- onload will only fire once everything has been loaded, all images etc. so your accordion should already be working and then afterwards you can call the twitter widget. Presumably the user would then see the twitter widget 'appear' as an added element to the page however.

info re `onload="myFunc()"` and the differences compared to `$(document).ready()` here...
[Difference between onload() and $.ready?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395780/difference-bw-onload-and-document-readyfunction)

see how it goes - if not, we'll think of something else.

S

******UPDATE 2******

Ok, so if you don't have access to the `<body>` tag try this:

in the block with accordion:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">First header</a></h3>
    <div>First content</div>
    <h3><a href="#">Second header</a></h3>
    <div>Second content</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code for accordion here eg...
       $('.accordion .head').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle('slow');
    return false;
   }).next().hide();
  });

</script>
```

and then in the block with the twitter widget:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  //your original twitter widget code
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 4,
  interval: 30000,
  width: 250,
  height: 350,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#5785BC',
      color: '#eff4fa',
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      color: '#424242',
      links: '#2480bd'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: false,
    live: false,
    behavior: 'all'
  }
}).render().setUser('Sometwitterpage').start();


</script>
```

See how that goes...

****UPDATE 3****

In the `<head>` you posted on jsfiddle there was the following includes:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.somewebsite.com/scripts/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js?m=20120904100316"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.somewebsite.com/scripts/jquery/jquery.prosteps.js?m=20120904100316"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.somewebsite.com/scripts/jquery/jquery.boxy.js?m=20120904100316"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.somewebsite.com/scripts/jquery/jquery.scroll-To.js?m=20120904100316"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.somewebsite.com/scripts/jquery/jquery.hoverIntent.js?m=20120904100316"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.somewebsite.com/scripts/jquery/jquery.jqzoom1.0.1.js?m=20120904100316"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.somewebsite.com/scripts/jquery/jquery.tools.scrollable.min.js?m=20120904100316">
```

Do you have the option of turning these features on/off - for example if you're not going to use a jquery tools scrollable, turn it off - i.e., don't include the source .js file. My guess is there's a very, very strong chance the problem is coming from conflicting variables so you could try to isolate it by turning off/on the various scripts. Getting rid of surplus is a definite starting point.

Comment: Sorry if I seem dumb but I don't understand where to put that script. I have to add I can't access the body element as there area we can edit is with in divs inside the body

Comment: what does the accordion element look like in your code and which cms are you using? p.s. lunctime - back in 30

Comment: Sorry the CMS is bespoke and works on some stupid block system to edit pages, each block is a self contained div. The accordion is the jquery-ui standard accordion

Comment: Unfortunately that hasn't done it. Its the <script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script> that causes the problem when I remove that it works but the twitter widget doesn't obviously

Comment: I am sure your answer is correct its just something that isn't working within this system

Comment: look at your code that calls the twitter widget `shell: {
      background: '#5785BC',
      color: '#eff4fa',
    }` - extra comma after '#eff4fa' - not necessarily related to the problem but it's amazing how an extra comma can consume a day of debugging!

Comment: Also, 'src="widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"' - is that filepath right? no protocol statement - http:// S

Comment: [link]http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js sorry thats the file url i think SO removed the http://

Comment: I corrected those last two points to no avail. thanks anyway for all your help

Comment: I am afraid all those files are required and I have no control over them. Thanks anyway you have been more than helpful

Comment: @Ashley Briscoe - don't know if you're still resolving the issue or not but if you are then you should definitely have a look at this - could free you from jquery-UI... [css3.bradshawenterprises.com/accordions/](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/accordions/)

Comment: That does seem like a great alternative. unfortunately the menu system is built on accordion and I do not have control over that. again thank you for your time and your help.

Comment: Ok Ashley - best of luck with your project! Feel free to @me if you have need. S

Comment: Thank you I will you have been very helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

May be a little simplisctic - and perhaps even not best practice - but have you tried changing the 'include' order - presumably you've got a

```
<script src="yourSource/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

I've had in the past - changed the order to include the other first and it started working. Not so satisfying as this doesn't actually identify the problem however it might get you rolling again...

S

Comment: due to the nature of the cms the ui script is in the head which I can't access and this twiiter script is included in the body

Comment: so are you saying the twitter script should be included first?

Comment: Is there any kind of no conflict script that can separate this from the ui script???

Comment: Yes - I was suggesting that but as you now describe, sure - that's not an option if you haven't access to the heasd includes. Hold on a minute... finding something here... back in moment...

Comment: start looking at this - I'm still trying to figure where to use it since you haven't access to the `<head>` of the doc. You can start trying tho'... http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: can you see the source of the `<head`> in your browser or firebug?

Comment: I had a look at noconflict but couldn't figure out where to use it

Comment: I will try and implement it first

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16235/discussion-between-scott-clark-and-ashley-briscoe)

Comment: Chat still wont work for me if you look at the fiddle I have included head code