# Jquery dont work but i guess everything is ok

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code, to do a basic slide show

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Slider()
        {
            $(".slider#1").show("fade",500);
        }
    </script>
```

than i have this div:

```
   <div class="slider">
        <img id="1" src="images/pic1.jpg" border="0" alt="Image"/>
        <img id="2" src="images/pic1.jpg" border="0" alt="Image"/>
        <img id="3" src="images/pic1.jpg" border="0" alt="Image"/>
     </div>
```

I also have onload in body to do jquery function when body loads:

```
<body onload="Slider()">
```

But nothing happens, what will be the error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### CSS IDs can't start with numbers

You can't start a CSS ID with a number, see here: http://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/

### You are selecting the child element

You are selecting the child element of `.slider`, so you need `.slider #i1`, see here: http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/

### $(document).ready

It's better to use `$(document).ready(function(){});` instead of `<body onload="Slider()">`, see here: [Difference between onload() and $.ready?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395780/difference-bw-onload-and-document-readyfunction)

### Your code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function Slider()
    {
        $(".slider #i1").show("fade",500);
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        Slider();
    });
</script>

<div class="slider">
     <img id="i1" src="images/pic1.jpg" border="0" alt="Image"/>
     <img id="i2" src="images/pic1.jpg" border="0" alt="Image"/>
     <img id="i3" src="images/pic1.jpg" border="0" alt="Image"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try `$(".slider #1").show("fade",500);`

So there's a space now between .slider and #1, meaning: look for an element with id '1' *inside* an element with class 'slider', which is what you want. What you had was: look for an element with id 'id' *and* class slider.

Comment: CSS IDs can't start with numbers: http://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/ See my answer

Comment: Just tried and that worked fine with jQuery in Chrome (did `$('<div id="1">hello</div>').appendTo('body')` and `$('#1');` right into the dev console in this SO page). Seems better practice though to not use it, I agree.

Comment: @Jochem Numerical ID's are valid in HTML(5), however not in CSS (without a little hack at least). It's always best practice to not use them.

Comment: @Jochem ya but not in CSS, e.g: #1{color:red;}

Answer (score 5):

**Fixing the error**

There is an error in your selector. You need a space between the class and the id. Also like Copy Devil said in his answer, you can't begin a css id with a number, so...

```
$(".slider #i1").show("fade",500);
```

**Good practices**

Instead of adding a onload tag to your body, it's considered good practice to do this instead.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slider #i1").show("fade",500);
});
```

This is known as [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). It avoids mixing HTML and javascript together.

Comment: I mean "correct" as "good practice". Both work fine, but the .ready is considered better since it's unobtrusive.

Comment: You edited your answer to address the problem I had with it, so I removed my comment :). I know it is a good practice, the problem is others might not. Just saying something was correct can be confusing to people if you don't explain why.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I thought about that after posting. That's what I get for going for speed instead of correctness.

Answer (score 1):

It's just the space missing. As others answered before,

```
".slider#1"
//something that has class=slider AND id=1
```

vs

```
".slider #1"
//something that has id=1 and IS INSIDE OF something with class=slider
```

Others suggested $(document).ready but body onload will do, you won't have to change that. (However it's better their way.)