# Difference and advantages of using $(document).ready instead of onload event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that `$(document).ready` provides a very efficient method to execute code after DOM is loaded and ready. In Js I used `<body onload="">` to accomplish the same result.

Anyone could explain me which are the advantages of using `$(document).ready` instead of a simple `onload` on body element?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395780/difference-between-onload-and-ready

Comment: Read the ready docs