# JavaScript - Loading the entire webpage not specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm sure that this is a very trivial fix. 
I'm dynamically changing a div content  based on which button is clicked. This example works in JSFiddle but however when I put it on my PC it simply loads the entire webpage even when I wrap the JS with `$(window).load(function(){ ... })`

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src= "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>


</head>

<body>


<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#about" class="menu-btn">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact" class="menu-btn">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#misc" class="menu-btn">Misc</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="about" class="menu-content">About</div>
<div id="contact" class="menu-content">Contact</div>
<div id="misc" class="menu-content">Misc</div>


</body>

</html>
```

My JS (script.js):

```
$(window).load(function(){


  var $content = $('.menu-content');

  function showContent(type) {
    $('div', $content).hide();
    $('div[data-menu-content='+type+']').show();
  }

  $('.menu').on('click', '.menu-btn', function(e) {
    showContent(e.currentTarget.hash.slice(1));
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  showContent('about');
});
```

Comment: use `$(function(){//code goes here})`

Answer (score 4):

```
$(window).load(function(){ ... })
```

replace by :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... })
```

Comment: OP said he is new to JS, care explaining how and why this fixes the issue?

Comment: We got no all the info about wich jquery version you are using but the reason why a page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you.

Comment: Headmax - This was correct and but also Nishesh answer below was also a part of the problem

Comment: @Sid i guess but this question is already documented explain here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395780/difference-between-onload-and-ready i hope that gave you some important info needed. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `(window).load` to `(document).ready`

`load` is called when all assets are done loading, including images. `ready` is fired when the DOM is ready for interaction.

**load()**

> The load event fires at the end of the
>   document loading process. At this
>   point, all of the objects in the
>   document are in the DOM, and all the
>   images and sub-frames have finished
>   loading.

**ready()**

> While JavaScript provides the load
>   event for executing code when a page
>   is rendered, this event does not get
>   triggered until all assets such as
>   images have been completely received.
>   In most cases, the script can be run
>   as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been
>   fully constructed. The handler passed
>   to .ready() is guaranteed to be
>   executed after the DOM is ready, so
>   this is usually the best place to
>   attach all other event handlers and
>   run other jQuery code. When using
>   scripts that rely on the value of CSS
>   style properties, it's important to
>   reference external stylesheets or
>   embed style elements before
>   referencing the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 


  var $content = $('.menu-content');

  function showContent(type) {
    $('div', $content).hide();
    $('div[data-menu-content='+type+']').show();
  }

  $('.menu').on('click', '.menu-btn', function(e) {
    showContent(e.currentTarget.hash.slice(1));
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  showContent('about');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below solution :

```
function showContent(type) {
    $($content).hide();
    $('#'+type).show();
  }
```

When i ran your snippet in my PC, I found out that Jquery was not able to find div, based on the selectors you have specified at the time of loading.

Comment: This was actually part of the problem, the second part was with 'headmax' answer above. Many Thanks