# Check if images are loaded?

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a sulotion that check if all images are loaded before they are used in a image slider/rotator. I was thinking of a solution that only show the buttons or thumbnails of the images when the main images are loaded to prevent user from clicking on an image that hasen't been downloaded completey.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I determine if an image has loaded, using Javascript/jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263359/how-can-i-determine-if-an-image-has-loaded-using-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The text from the [.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) jQuery docs might help make the distinction between `load` and `ready` more clear:

> While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets such as images have been completely received. In most cases, the script can be run as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully constructed. The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code.

... and from the [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) docs:

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.

So `.load` is what you're looking for. What's great about this event is that you can attach it to only a subset of the DOM. Let's say you have your slideshow images in a div like this:

```
<div class="slideshow" style="display:none">
  <img src="image1.png"/>
  <img src="image2.png"/>
  <img src="image3.png"/>
  <img src="image4.png"/>
  <img src="image5.png"/>
</div>
```

... then you could use `.load` just on the `.slideshow` container to trigger once all of the images in the container have been loaded, regardless of other images on the page.

```
$('.slideshow img').load(function(){
  $('.slideshow').show().slideshowPlugin();
});
```

(I put in a `display:none` just as an example. It would hide the images while they load.)

**Update (03.04.2013)**
This method is deprecated since jQuery Version 1.8

Comment: why would they deprecate such a great function? *arg* now we have to use a 7kb file like http://www.desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/ :(

Comment: @DoJoChi Actually, I don't think you necessarily have to load another file.  From the documentation, the replacement for ``.load`` is using the appropriate arguments to ``.on`` (http://api.jquery.com/on/), e.g. ``.on('load', handler)``

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger off each `$('img').load()` event and enable the related link / click event only once your load has triggered.  Advantage to doing it image by image is if certain images are taking longer to load you could still allow the quick ones to be 'clickable'.

```
$('img').load(function() {
    // find the related link or click event and enable/add it
});
```

Comment: Then I have to use an ID for each image?

Comment: @user637364 you could or if you images are wrapped in <a> tags you could just reference the container.  You could also share css names between the img and the anchors etc... lots of options for relating the img.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than checking if all images are loaded, why not create the slider/rotator using the `$(window).load()` event, rather than the usual `$(document).ready()`? `$(window).load()` waits for the page to finish loading, including resources such as images, before executing.

See: [window.onload vs. body.onload vs. document.onready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474037/window-onload-vs-body-onload-vs-document-onready) (also on Stack Overflow).