# jquery slider doesn't work until refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, refresh, slideshow

I have a simple jquery slideshow that should start when my homepage is loaded.  It works, but only after I refresh the page once or twice.  Here is the code I am using:

```
    <!-- include jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
    <!-- include Cycle plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Jquery2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.image').cycle({
          fx: 'fade',
          random: '1'
          });});      
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance!!

-Theo

Comment: This should work as it states right now. Try to use `$(window).load(function(){ /*code here*/ });` insead of document ready. I suppose it's about images widths, heights and so on...

Comment: Did you put all your javascript code at the end of body?

Comment: @RDSAGAR no. what's the difference if you use `$(function(){` that means the DOM is ready.

Comment: `random: '1'` to  `random: 1`

Comment: @user1042031 than it would break always if that were the main reason.

Comment: @roXon : Sorry my mistake :D .. OP could you please post ur markup ?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('.image').cycle({
      fx: 'fade',
      random: '1'
      });});      
</script>
```

With

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() { 
$('.image').cycle({
      fx: 'fade',
      random: '1'
      });});      
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all images is not loaded

```
$('img').load(function() {
    $('.image').cycle({
          fx: 'fade',
          random: '1'
          });});      
});
```

Read more : [Check if images are loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424055/check-if-images-are-loaded)