# Using load function instead of ready function in jquery Cycle slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

This is part of my code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
$('#slideshow').cycle({
fx: 'cover',
speed: 2500,
timeout: 2000
});
}); 
</script>
```

I want to use load function instead of ready, because I want my slideshow to be started after all images are completely loaded.

In stackoverflow question below, it's suggested to use this code:

[Check if images are loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424055/check-if-images-are-loaded)

```
$('.slideshow img').load(function(){
$('.slideshow').show().cycle();
});
```

and also display the images in the body tag as : none.
when I apply this code to my own slideshow (without displaying the images as none), my slideshow doesn't start.

How I should write this code?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $('#slideshow').cycle({
     fx: 'cover',
     speed: 2500,
     timeout: 2000
   });
});
```

This should wait to all content and graphics are loaded before running the cycle.

Comment: thank you a lot . It works . 
but I think i will have another problem
because the images are in body tag and my script is separate from 
the html , before the slide show starts , images will form a queue from top to down of the slideshow div tag  during the loading time. 
am I right ?

because I'm working with localhost and speed is high , I don't know it happens or not .

again thank you , anyway

Comment: Have a look here http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/ - $(window).load will wait until all content is loaded - meaning the HTLM has rendedred as well as all iFrames and Images etc. I don't understand what the issue would be?!?

Comment: ok . thank you . if it includes all the content and components 
there will be no problem