# How to tell if this image has loaded

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code on my page:

```
<div class="titleCard" id="first" style="background-image:url('img/path.jpg'); filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='img/path.jpg',sizingMethod='scale'); -ms-filter: \"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='img/path.jpg',sizingMethod='scale')\";">
```

How in jquery can I test whether the image has loaded? I want to have a title fade up on top of the image once it's done loading.

This seems to be different from other loading issues because the .load() function doesn't work here -- the image has no id. Calling it '#first' or '#first img' also doesn't work. I don't want to check whether *all* images or loaded, just this one. Binding the load function also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424055/check-if-images-are-loaded) or [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached) might help

Comment: These answers aren't working for me.

Comment: using `.load()` is tough because it creates issues if the image is cached

Comment: Have you read "Caveats of the load event when used with images" on the documentation page?

Comment: @LauraNMS look at this plugin https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

Comment: I don't believe CSS background had load events.

Comment: @Diodeus: I think that's what I'm running up against.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS to load the image in memory and listen to the onload event there. You'll need to set the default opacity, then fade in on your onload event.

```
var tmp = new Image();
tmp.onload = function() { ... };
tmp.src = "....";
```