# check if an image is visible in a jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

here is the jsfiddle of my slider http://jsfiddle.net/jdDYQ/7/ All the images are loaded at once I only want to load the visible one for that I will need to know if they are visible or not. Does anyone know how to do it ?

Thanks.

```
<div class="wrapper" style="width:288px;overflow:hidden">
 <ul class="ui" style="width:3000px">
 <li><img class='lazy_1' src="image.png" alt="" class=""/></li>
 <li><img class='lazy_2' src="image.png" alt="" class=""/></li>
 <li><img class='lazy_4' src="image.png" alt="" class=""/></li>
 <li><img class='lazy_5' src="image.png" alt="" class=""/></li>
 <li><img class='lazy_6' src="image.png" alt="" class=""/></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: probably [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424055/check-if-images-are-loaded) can help, or do you mean: visible and do not brocken?

Answer (score 0):

The following returns `true` if selected element is visible and `false` otherwise:

```
if ($(selector).is(':visible')) {
  //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

btw, you have two `class=""` inside each element.

you can check if element is visible by

```
$('#some_id').is(":visible")
```

Comment: Yes ok I can do that, but first I have to load only visible image of the slider for the perfomances and then load once they are visible