# Accessing controls early | load vs. domready

Tags: javascript

I was on jsfiddle.net recently and I saw this as a configuration option.  This got me to thinking that it might help a problem I'm having as such:

I load multiple images (haven't upgraded to a single sprite yet) so that I can not use my controls until they are all downloaded...the images take most of the download time so that for the first few seconds I can not access my controls.

Currently I'm using one of these two..both work.

```
window.onload = initialize_page

window.addEventListener('load',initialize_page);
```

**Related**

[Jquery document ready vs. window.onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)

[window.onload vs. body.onload vs. document.onready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474037/window-onload-vs-body-onload-vs-document-onready)

[window.onload vs <body onload=""/>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191157/window-onload-vs-body-onload)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK `onDomReady()` fires once the DOM has loaded. If the page contains external sources, such as images, then it may fire before these have finished loading.
`onLoad()` fires after the whole page has finished loading, including external sources.

So it's possible for `onDomReady()` to fire before `onLoad()` but you'll have to test it on your page.

Comment: @stack.user.0: `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){//},false);`. See http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/DOMContentLoaded/Default.html

Comment: Unfortunately that event is not fired on Safari or IE, the two broswers I'm targeting...thanks for the info though