# Try to call function defined in external js from jquery $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

Aim: When html page loads successfully, jquery **$(document).ready** gets called, then call function defined in external js inside **$(document).ready**.

**Note: jquery lib included**

**hello.js**

```
function hello(){
  alert('hello');
}
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="hello.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  hello();
});
```

Above code doesn't trigger alert. New to js and jquery. Better solutions are welcomed. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure `hello.js' %}` is correct ? or should be like this `{% 'hello.js' %}` ?

Comment: Sorry, bad copy/paste. Question updated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing controls early | load vs. domready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934993/accessing-controls-early-load-vs-domready)

Comment: Theoretically it could also be possible that your inline code runs before hello.js is loaded.

Comment: @blanknamefornow baby wakes up early. Check your solution later. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you have included hello.js in root directory then try to use this syntax:

```
   <script src="~/hello.js"></script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     hello();
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to waste everyone's time. It was due to an javascript syntax error (missing close bracket due to bad copy/paste).