# Access function in a JS page from another JS page on page load

Tags: jquery, asp.net, javascript

Let name it as A.js and B.js.

On page load of an aspx page, I am trying to load JS in the order A.js,B.js.

I used a method in B.js which is declared in A.js. But I am getting an error function undeclared alert in console.

But when I tried alerting either from B.js or A.js, script is working fine. It is taking the method and page is good. Why so?

What I need to do for making it work without alerting?

Comment: I would assume you should call B.anyMethod(..) which calls A.someOtherMethod() on document.ready of your html file.

Comment: Document ready is about DOM, not js scripts.

Comment: thx for the reminder @RafałŁużyński. so what about using [.load(..)](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

Comment: load is ok, but it works just for one element, so you have to implement your own onJavaScriptsLoad event when all scripts are loaded.

Comment: i checked out window.load which raises an event if all assets of a page have been loaded - correct?

Answer (score 1):

Scripts are loaded asynchronously, so you never know which file will load first. Most probably  one with less bytes.

If you want to load scripts in order you provide, use library like [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I did a small example and used **window.load event** which did work for me. Check out [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474037/window-onload-vs-body-onload-vs-document-onready) on SO or [**jquery.load**](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="a.js"></script>
    <script src="b.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("load", function () {
            methodB();
        }, false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried. Same effect. will work if we set alert or debugger. If not, it wont .. :(

Comment: can u edit your question and show a bit more code and/or send me the complete example by mail -franz.pilgerstorfer@gmx.at