# Difference between window load and window ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between

```
 $(window).load(function () {});
```

And

```
 $(window).ready(function () {});
```

What is the difference between window load and window ready?

Comment: jQuery treats `$(anything).ready()` as `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: Thanks, Barmar.  very useful info,

Comment: Where can I find the duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

window.ready occurs when all of the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) has been loaded but images may not have been loaded

window load occurs after all images have finished loading

ready event happens first so most code can be placed her

[window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)

Answer (score 0):

- `document.ready` is a jQuery event, it runs when the DOM is ready
- `window.onload` fires later when images and such are loaded

Example Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 // executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready
 alert("document is ready");
});


$(window).load(function() {
 // executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images
 alert("window is loaded");
});
```

Refer

[Difference between window load and window ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20418169/difference-between-window-load-and-window-ready/)

[window.onload vs. body.onload vs. document.onready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474037/window-onload-vs-body-onload-vs-document-onready)