# Does body onload happen before window.onload?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on the following. It basically passes ?answer=1 if js is enabled. It works until I add the onload argument (as I want this to happen without a user trigger). However adding onload appears to stop (the otherwise working) getElementById argument. Why is this happening?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById('answer').value = '1';
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="document.forms[0].submit();">
<form name="form" action="enabled_catch.php" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="answer">
</form>
```

thanks

Comment: They're the same thing - in other words, `window.onload` refers to the same thing as the `onload` attribute of the `<body>` tag.

Comment: Also, you're using `getElementById()` but your input element has no "id" attribute - that works in IE because IE is broken, but it won't work in proper browsers.

Comment: so why does body onload appear to stop window.onload from working?

Comment: Because there are not two different `onload` handlers - you assign the first handler in your `<script>` block, and then when the browser sees your `<body>` tag it reassigns the handler to *that* code.  You can't have a single attribute pointing at two different handlers.

Comment: this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191157/window-onload-vs-body-onload

Comment: to answer your question, if you set both body.onload and window.onload one will overwrite the other.  

like 
a = b
a = c

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("answer").value = '1';
  document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

As I said in my comment, `window.onload` is the same thing as the "onload" handler for the `<body>` tag. You can't have one be one function and the other be another function, therefore, because the "other" isn't really another thing - it's the same thing.

Also, your `<input>` element needs an "id":

```
<input type='hidden' name='answer' id='answer'>
```