# Computing the size of a <canvas> on load?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
    canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
</style>

<script>
    function init() {
        canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        alert(canvas.width + "x" + canvas.height);
    }
</script>

</head>

<body onload="init();">
    <canvas id="canvas"> </canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

This code displays the size before it has been styled. I need the size after it has been styles. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem stems from the difference between the intrinsic dimensions of the canvas and the number of CSS pixels it takes up. The [HTML specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#the-canvas-element) says:

> The intrinsic dimensions of the canvas
>   element equal the size of the
>   coordinate space, with the numbers
>   interpreted in CSS pixels. However,
>   the element can be sized arbitrarily
>   by a style sheet. During rendering,
>   the image is scaled to fit this layout
>   size.

What this means is that your canvas defaults to a drawing space of 300x150px in terms of the coordinates used to draw images. However, your CSS rules will stretch the canvas to the size of the page (at least with regard to width). There will still only be 300px wide to logically draw on, but it will be scaled and physically rendered on whatever 100% of the page width corresponds to.

Anyway, the `width` and `height` properties correspond to the intrinsic drawing dimensions of the canvas. Since you care about the CSS size, you can use [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3awindow.getComputedStyle).

http://jsfiddle.net/3DDsX/

```
<head>
  <style>
    canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
  </style>
  <script>
    function init() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
      var style = getComputedStyle(canvas);
      alert(style.width + ' x ' + style.height);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks ide. I set the canvas size programaticly now on load and window resize so I get the correct amount of pixels to draw to.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the onload function in body, but you can use window.onload instead:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function onLoadDoIt() 
            {
                alert(document.getElementById("mydiv"));  
            }
            window.onload = onLoadDoIt;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mydiv">test</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191157/window-onload-vs-body-onload