# Diagnosing body.onload not being called

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have some web pages which rely on `body.onload` (or, equivalently, `window.onload`) to set them up properly. Sometimes `onload` is not being called.

Is there a trick with some web browser (ideally Chrome, where this apparently happens most often) which will tell me **what exactly is preventing the page from loading** successfully?

Clue: this rarely (maybe even never) happens when I hit F5 to reload the whole page, but more generally it happens if a page has been arrived-at by clicking a link or pasting the url into the address bar. Is there a quirk of `onload` semantics that might be tripping me up?

N.B. The scripts themselves are not producing any errors in the console.

Comment: *"I am happy to accept a "don't-use-onload" solution provided that I can hook into a cross-platform event which happens after the DOM is fully loaded."* If you're in control of where your script tags go, just put them at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want `window.onload`

Comment: Apparently they are [the same event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191157/window-onload-vs-body-onload) and when I experimented that didn't fix it. I still need to find out why the page isn't loading.

Comment: Yes `onload` is the same event, but attaching it to `window` vs. `body` is _not_ the same.  That said, sounds like you have something else going on.  What's your JS console say?

Comment: As stated in the question, the console is empty.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested such cases, and none of the following will work:

```
var callback = function() { alert("Body loaded"); };
$("body").load(callback);
document.body.addEventListener("load",callback,false);
```

However, `document.body.onload` seems to work fine. Make sure that `body` is correctly namespaced:

```
document.body //<body>
body //Reference error
```

If you're talking about:

```
<body onload="callback();"></body>
```

Then go back and review your code, because it should work.

---

Personally, I suggest using the `load` event of the window object or a framework's ready event.

```
//Execute when the window is loaded
var callback = function() {
     //Your code goes here...
};
if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener("load",callback,false);
else window.attachEvent("load",callback);
```

With jQuery, you only need the following:

```
$(window).load(callback);
```

jQuery's ready event is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(callback);
//Or just:
$(callback);
```

MooTools use this:

```
window.addEvent("domready",callback);
```

And different libraries all have their own way.