# Auto-refresh Javascript For RSS Using Google Feed API

Tags: javascript, rss, google-feed-api

I apologize if the title is trash. What I'd like to do is rather simple in concept... but I'm having a bit of trouble.

I would like to automatically refresh an RSS feed that is displayed using Google Feed API. I haven't worked with the Google Feed API before, but it seemed like a quick option for getting this rolled out. Technically, it only needs to be the content part that is reloaded.

The purpose: This is displaying the results of a poll, refreshing them every 3 seconds (it will be displayed in a presentation.) The actual result is in the 'content', whereas the item being voted on is the 'title'.

The unstyled basics of the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var feedcontainer=document.getElementById("feeddiv");
var feedurl="http://theurl.com";
var feedlimit=100;
var rssoutput="<b>Latest Results:</b><br /><ul>";

function rssfeedsetup(){
var feedpointer=new google.feeds.Feed(feedurl) //Google Feed API method
feedpointer.setNumEntries(feedlimit) //Google Feed API method
feedpointer.load(displayfeed) //Google Feed API method
}

function displayfeed(result){
if (!result.error){
var thefeeds=result.feed.entries
for (var i=0; i<thefeeds.length; i++)
rssoutput+="<li>" + thefeeds[i].title + "<br />" + thefeeds[i].content + "</li>"
rssoutput+="</ul>"
feedcontainer.innerHTML=rssoutput
}
else
alert("Error fetching feeds!")
}

window.onload=function(){
rssfeedsetup()
}

</script>
```

I'm not sure how to go about making the results refresh every 3 seconds. I've tried a few things, like "[How to autorefresh XML in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129238/how-to-autorefresh-xml-in-javascript)" but wound up printing the results multiple times on the page.

Major bonus points for anyone that can point me towards turning it into an auto refreshing bar graph. That will be my next search or question on here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call rssfeedsetup() in a setInterval function. Something like

```
  window.onload = function() {
    var delay = 3000;
    rssfeedsetup();
    setInterval(rssfeedsetup, delay);
  }
```

Comment: Good thinking. I tried it and I think it was basically what I had tried before - which results in it being printed over and over on the page. i.e. after 6 seconds there are 3 instances of it on the page.

Comment: well, I think that is because of the variable 'rssoutput'. It is not being reset and instead is being appended to. Initially, set rssoutput to = "". Then in your displayfeed function, set rssoutput to = "<b>Latest Results:</b><br /><ul>"