# Show/Hide DIV section onchange and onload with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, xslt

I thought I had this figured out but I was wrong. I have a xsl form that I would like to toggle or show/hide a section when a specific value is selected or present on the form. I'm limited to JavaScript and I appreciate all the help.

1. When user selects option, hidden div section shows and
2. When form is loaded and that value is present, div section shows

Here is the sample HTML I would like to work from to figure this out:

```
<select name="sbFruit" id="sbFruit" style="display:none;" title="Select your Fruit">
  <xsl:variable name="sbFruit" select="Fruit" />
  <xsl:for-each select="document('FRUIT_Lookups.xml')/lookups/FruitTypes/Fruit">
    <xsl:variable name="optFruit" select="value" />
    <option>
      <xsl:if test="$sbFruit = $optFruit">
        <xsl:attribute name="selected">true</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
    </option>
  </xsl:for-each>
</select>

<!-- Toggled Group when 'sbFruit' = Orange -->
<div id="AppleSubGroup" name="AppleSubGroup" style="display: none;>"
  <label id="Orange_Fresh">Is the Orange Fresh?</label>
  <input name="Fresh" type="radio" value="Yes" />Yes
  <input name="Fresh" type="radio" value="No" />No
  <br />
  <label id="Orange_moldy">Is the Orange moldy?</label>
  <input name="Red" type="radio" value="Yes" />Yes
  <input name="Red" type="radio" value="No" />No
</div>
```

XML Fruit Choices:

```
Apple
Blueberry
Orange
Pear
```

or Simple HTML Version:

```
<select id="sbFruit" name="sbFruit">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Blueberry</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
  <option>Pear</option>
</select>

<!-- Toggled Group when 'sbFruit' = Orange -->
<div id="AppleSubGroup" name="AppleSubGroup" style="display: none;>"
  <label id="Orange_Fresh">Is the Orange Fresh?</label>
  <input name="Fresh" type="radio" value="Yes" />Yes
  <input name="Fresh" type="radio" value="No" />No
  <br />
  <label id="Orange_moldy">Is the Orange moldy?</label>
  <input name="Red" type="radio" value="Yes" />Yes
  <input name="Red" type="radio" value="No" />No
</div>
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: try to change the display class of the div that you wanna show or hide to (block/none)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/h8798/) and see if this is what you need. It is a very basic version but still does the work.

Basically, you need to do the following:

1. Assign a `value` attribute to all your options (say `AppleSubGroup` for the option `Apple`). The value assigned for each option must match the ID of the Div which has contents related to it. Else this won't work.
2. Specify two classes namely `hidden` and `visible` with rules as `display:none` and `display:block` respectively. This when assigned to your sub groups will show/hide them.
3. Write a JS function to assign the hidden/visible classes to the sub groups based on selection. I am assuming you want a JS only version (if you are ok with jQuery, refer to Ambroos' answer)
4. Invoke this function on page load using `window.onload = showHide;`. This will set the sub group corresponding to the default selected value as visible on page load.
5. Add the `onChange="showHide();"` attribute to your `select` tag. This will invoke the function every time the selection is modified.

Note: I have added a wrapper div with `id="SubGroup"` to your sub groups section.

```
window.onload = showHide;

function showHide(){
    var el = document.getElementById("sbFruit");
    var selectedVal = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
    var subGroupEl = document.getElementById("SubGroup").getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(var i=0; i<subGroupEl.length; i++){
        subGroupEl[i].className = "hidden";
    }
    document.getElementById(selectedVal).className = "visible";
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works great. Only one issue I'm having is I only need to have this work for one of my options the rest do not need sub-Groups. In my environment it doesn't like the null values. How can I adjust the JS to accommodate this?

Comment: second question on #4 can I just add that to my <body onload="formLoad(); showHide;"> tag? and remove it from the JS? What is the pro/con to doing so?

Comment: There is not much difference between the two and either can be used but I prefer the `window.onload`. Check [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191157/window-onload-vs-body-onload) SO post for more information.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice your first question earlier. Check [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/h8798/) fiddle and see if it matches your need. I have added an `if` loop to check if a Sub Group exists and then show if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery and the HTML version this should be very easy. You assign a handler that checks if the option is checked, and if it is, show or hide the div.

```
$("select[name='sbFruit']").change(function(event) {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Orange') {
        $('#OrangeSubGroup').hide();
    } else {
        $('#OrangeSubGroup').show();
    }
}).trigger('change');
```

The `.trigger('change')` makes sure the check is done on load too. How it'd be for the XML form, I don't know. It might work with this code.