# window onload conflicts with body onload javascript

Tags: javascript

My client puts our below JS code in his website in the `<head>` and is complaining our tags are not firing. Below is the sample code from client:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function create() {
    try {
    var baseURL = "https://serv2ssl.vizury.com/analyze/analyze.php?account_id=VIZVRM1125";
    var analyze = document.createElement("iframe");
    analyze.src = baseURL;
    var node = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    node.parentNode.insertBefore(analyze, node);
} catch (i) {
}
}
 var existing = window.onload;
window.onload = function() {
if (existing) {
    existing();
}
create();
}
  </script>
 </head>

 <body onload="javascript:clientfunction();">
 <script type="text/javascript">

function clientfunction()
{
   //client code is replcad here
   document.write("Hello testing");
}
 </script>

  </body>
 </html>
```

On page Load `clientfunction()` is calling, our `create()` function is not firing.

Please can anybody help me why our tags are not firing and what is the alternative solution for this issue?

Comment: Read more about [window.onload vs <body onload=""/>](http://stackoverflow.com/a/191318/684932)

Answer (score -1):

copy paste and check running following

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function create() {
alert("Gdfg");
try {
var baseURL = "https://serv2ssl.vizury.com/analyze/analyze.php?account_id=VIZVRM1125";
var analyze = document.createElement("iframe");
analyze.src = baseURL;
var node = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
node.parentNode.insertBefore(analyze, node);
} catch (i) {
}
}

window.onload=create;
window.onload=clientfunction;
</script>
</head>

<body onload="clientfunction(); create()">
<script type="text/javascript">

function clientfunction()
{
alert("fdsfsdf");
//client code is replcad here
document.write("Hello testing");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Only the bottom executes, doesn't it?

Comment: no both are working fine, i am editing my post to give you complete code.

Comment: @SKV Both are working fine because you've stuck them in the `onload` attribute of the `<body>` tag, but that's an absolute hack. You're also losing any previously declared `window.onload` function, and the code in the question is making a specific effort for that *not* to be the case.

Comment: What happens if the client's function (or for that matter, a different client using the same code) changes the name of it?