# Difference between window.onload = function () vs window.onload=

Tags: javascript, bind, return-value

Hello I have an aspx document, at the bottom of the page I have this code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = migrate();
</script>
```

It works well, but it does a flickering in the page. The flickering is because I use a translation system...
But if I put:

```
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     window.onload = function () {
            migrate();
        }
    </script>
```

The flickering dissapear.

What is the difference?

Thanks!

Comment: the first one should be `window.onload = migrate;`

Comment: @^ "window.onload = migrate;" is similar to what question owner wrote in 2nd block. Perhaps, he wants to know the difference between 1st and 2nd block what would happen.

Answer (score 3):

In the first code snippet, you are calling the `migrate()` function and assigning it the value returned from `window.onload`. (Assuming `migrate()` returns a function object).

In the second code snippet, you are defining the `onload` function which in turn will call the `migrate()` method.

Comment: just to further explain things: in the first block you are defining that the `onload` event executes what `migrate()` returns (because of the paranthesis). If you want to run `migrate` as a function, set `window.onload = migrate;`

Comment: Is it logic to asign something to onload of window?

Comment: It is. window.onload=migrate;  => when window loads this method will be called and the argument passed will be an Event object (load event). Also another way of this is <body onload='migrate()'>..</body>

Comment: You can see the comparison of them here (there is few differences, yes). - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191157/window-onload-vs-body-onload