# Make javascript load after content

Tags: css

i have a banner ad on the top of my page and it makes the rest of the page wait for it before loading.
And this is slow.
I cannot use the async property because the ad doesn't work well with it.

Can someone tell me another method to load this javascript after the body loaded?

I've read about placing the js at the footer and positioning the ad with css on top but i don't know how to achieve this, and i'm a little scared google might penalize it (they penalize everything this days).

So yeah what are the best ways?

Comment: possible duplicate of [window.onload vs <body onload=""/>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191157/window-onload-vs-body-onload)

Comment: It doesn't answer my question.

Comment: It depends on how the ad javascript works, so how does it work? What happens when you use `async`?

Comment: it gives error because document.write cannot be used with javascripts loaded async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds kind of like the ad insertion works by appearing wherever you insert the `<script>` tag. If so, that is a terrible and antiquated method, and there will be no work around without changing how that script works.

However, most ad servers these days have a more elegant way to load ads. They probably have documentation about how they work, and I couldn't begin to speculate about what the ad network you are using recommends. You should ask them.