# JavaScript "Undefined", Why? I just defined it

Tags: javascript, undefined

I have this:

```
<script id="wpcp_css_disable_selection" type="text/javascript">
    var e = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    e.setAttribute('unselectable','on');
</script>
```

How come that the console throws this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined
```

Comment: If `getElementsByTagName` doesn't return any elements, getting element `[0]` will return `undefined`.

Comment: You know you can just do `document.body`, assuming the element is available of course, which it seems it's not !

Comment: If that `<script>` is in the `<head>`, then the `<body>` won't be in the DOM yet when the code runs.

Comment: @"Edward Norton": Could you give us feedback to avoid speculative answers/comments?

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

and

```
<script id="wpcp_css_disable_selection" type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction(){
    var e = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    e.setAttribute('unselectable','on');
  };      
</script>
```

which makes sure, DOM is set up and then function will be called. i suspect DOM is not ready yet when your function is called. just a guess. may also be wrong

Comment: onload is never a good idea when you may depend, now or later, on external ressources.

Comment: "External ressources" might be a facebook javascript, a JS externally stored, or a lot of other things you have no control on. When the servers you don't own are not responding (or are affected by network issues), the load event can happen too late.

Comment: Your code cares about the same than window.onload. Unless I'm wrong and [an accepted answer well rated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/191318/1106814) too. And if this question author don't ask about external resources, unless he explicitly tells he is sure to never use them, why encourage to something that seems to be, in a general case, a bad habit causing hard to reproduce bugs?

Answer (score -1):

I think the `body` element should be in the HTML page. You can check it like this:

```
var e = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
if(typeof e != 'undefined'){
    e[0].setAttribute('unselectable','on');
}
```

Comment: All this does is suppress the error. It doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: @Juhana: Although I disagree with this code alone, preventing `Uncaught TypeError` is far from doing anything.

Comment: @dotpush Right, but the OP's goal is to set the "unselectable" attribute on the body tag. This code doesn't do that. This is equivalent of just commenting out the whole code.

Comment: That's why I started the comment by saying I disagree with the code of the answer.