# How to execute a js function onload?

Tags: javascript, initialization, tableau-api, onload

Below is a fully functional and working code . When I copy paste it to a text file `testFile.html` and then open it with a browser it works fine.

But I want the `selectCollege` function to execute right after the `initViz` function

I tried this

`<body onload="initViz();selectCollege('Engineering');"> . . .`

But it didn't work. How can I make the `selectCollege` function to execute right after the `initViz` ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Select Marks</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/tableau-2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var viz, sheet;

        function initViz() {
            var containerDiv = document.getElementById("vizContainer"),
                url = "http://public.tableau.com/views/RegionalSampleWorkbook/College",
                options = {
                    "Academic Year": "",
                    hideTabs: true,
                    onFirstInteractive: function () {
                        sheet = viz.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet();
                    }
                };

            viz = new tableau.Viz(containerDiv, url, options);
        }

        function selectCollege(college_name) {
            sheet.selectMarksAsync("College", college_name, tableau.SelectionUpdateType.REPLACE);
        }

     </script>
</head>

<body onload="initViz();">
    <div id="vizContainer"></div>
    <br />    
    <button onclick="selectCollege('Engineering');">Select a value</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `<body onload="initViz();selectCollege('Engineering');>` -> `<body onload="initViz();selectCollege('Engineering');">` (note the missing `"` in the example you gave)

Comment: Why just dont add `selectCollege('Engineering')` at the end of initViz function

Comment: Depends on if you want before or after dom has rendered. You could just run the command without init

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yes it;s a typo in the question. in my file I have the `quote` i use a color coding editor. So the quote is there, but still doesn't work

Comment: Well, I also notice that `sheet` isn't initialized until `onFirstInteractive()` is invoked, so maybe what you're requesting is impossible. What does the error log say when you try my suggestion? My guess is that it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectMarksAsync' of undefined`

Comment: @Frankusky I tried adding it at the end of `initViz` with no result

Comment: @PatrickRoberts maybe it is impossible. i tried all answers below. None of the solutions work with that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `selectCollege()` you are attempting to access `sheet` before it is defined in the callback function from the `tableau.Viz` `options` object, namely `onFirstInteractive()`. In order to solve this, you can call the function after defining `sheet` in that function:

```
options = {
  ...
  onFirstInteractive: function () {
    sheet = viz.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet();
    selectCollege('Engineering');
  }
};
```

And according to [this forum](https://community.tableau.com/thread/150900), `onFirstInteractive()` will be called once when your instance of `tableau.Viz` is first rendered.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH. THIS IS THE ONLY WORKING ANSWER

Answer (score 3):

Create a new function

```
function init(){
  initViz();
  selectCollege('Engineering');
}
```

Then call the init function

```
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: That will make the functions run in parallel, not after the first function

Comment: Of interest, as I just had to look it up, the effect of `window.onload` is identical to `body onload`, but [there are good reasons to prefer the first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/191318/1270789).

Comment: @Frankusky that statement is completely invalid. JavaScript is single-threaded, and this does indeed invoke `initViz()` and then `selectCollege()` sequentually.

Answer (score 2):

```js
 function initViz(college_name) {
 //your code

            viz = new tableau.Viz(containerDiv, url, options);
            
            //then
            selectCollege('engineering');
        }

        function selectCollege(college_name) {
            sheet.selectMarksAsync("College", college_name, tableau.SelectionUpdateType.REPLACE);
        }
```

Use it like this

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```js
function bar() {
  alert("bar");
}
function foo() {
  alert("foo");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="bar();foo();">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
<body>
... All other tags..
<script>
//just before closing body
function(){

}()
</script>
</body>
....
```

Call your function just before closing body within a script tag.

HTML tree interpreted sequentially. So that's how I add loading message for SPAs.