# I want to add onload='startGame()' in my div

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add this function on div rather then body

```
<body onload="startGame()"> = Wrong
```

Like

```
<div id="gmdemo" onload="startGame()"> = Right
```

When i add this function on div then the code not running

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <style>
    canvas {
        border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="startGame()">
    <script>
    var myGamePiece;
    var myObstacles = [];
    var myScore;
    function startGame() {
        myGamePiece = new component(20, 20, "red", 10, 120);
        myGamePiece.gravity = 0.05;
        myScore = new component("30px", "Consolas", "black", 280, 40, "text");
        myGameArea.start();
    }
    
    var myGameArea = {
        canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
        start : function() {
            this.canvas.width = 480;
            this.canvas.height = 270;
            this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
            document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
            this.frameNo = 0;
            this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
            },
        clear : function() {
            this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        }
    }
    
    function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
        this.type = type;
        this.score = 0;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.speedX = 0;
        this.speedY = 0;    
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.gravity = 0;
        this.gravitySpeed = 0;
        this.update = function() {
            ctx = myGameArea.context;
            if (this.type == "text") {
                ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
                ctx.fillStyle = color;
                ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
            } else {
                ctx.fillStyle = color;
                ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
            }
        }
        this.newPos = function() {
            this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
            this.x += this.speedX;
            this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
            this.hitBottom();
        }
        this.hitBottom = function() {
            var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
            if (this.y > rockbottom) {
                this.y = rockbottom;
                this.gravitySpeed = 0;
            }
        }
        this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
            var myleft = this.x;
            var myright = this.x + (this.width);
            var mytop = this.y;
            var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
            var otherleft = otherobj.x;
            var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
            var othertop = otherobj.y;
            var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
            var crash = true;
            if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
                crash = false;
            }
            return crash;
        }
    }
    
    function updateGameArea() {
        var x, height, gap, minHeight, maxHeight, minGap, maxGap;
        for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
            if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
                return;
            } 
        }
        myGameArea.clear();
        myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
        if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
            x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
            minHeight = 20;
            maxHeight = 200;
            height = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxHeight-minHeight+1)+minHeight);
            minGap = 50;
            maxGap = 200;
            gap = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxGap-minGap+1)+minGap);
            myObstacles.push(new component(10, height, "green", x, 0));
            myObstacles.push(new component(10, x - height - gap, "green", x, height + gap));
        }
        for (i = 5; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
            myObstacles[i].x += -1;
            myObstacles[i].update();
        }
        myScore.text="SCORE: " + myGameArea.frameNo;
        myScore.update();
        myGamePiece.newPos();
        myGamePiece.update();
    }
    
    function everyinterval(n) {
        if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {return true;}
        return false;
    }
    
    function accelerate(n) {
        myGamePiece.gravity = n;
    }
    </script>
    <br>
    <button onmousedown="accelerate(-0.2)" onmouseup="accelerate(0.05)">ACCELERATE</button>
    <p>Use the ACCELERATE button to stay in the air</p>
    <p>How long can you stay alive?</p>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you cannot attach onload event on div. onload event only works with body

Comment: what you actually want to achieve, why you need this please explain ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add onload event to a div element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057236/how-to-add-onload-event-to-a-div-element)

Comment: Can you just stop asking the same questions again and again? It is very annoying and is considered **noise** in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to add `onload` to a div.

```
<div id="gmdemo">Some content</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   startGame('gmdemo');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no onload for divs or most of DOM elements (with some exceptions). Please take a look to this old post: [window.onload vs <body onload=""/>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191157/window-onload-vs-body-onload)

Answer (score 1):

You can't add onload on div. what you can do is to put the function call directly after the element

```
...
<div id="gmdemo">Some content</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   startGame();
</script>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

As is stated here: [How to add onload event to a div element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057236/how-to-add-onload-event-to-a-div-element)

You cannot add an onload event onto a div. However, you could put the call to the function directly into the div as is shown in the linked question.