# Function is not running with `<body onload="myFunction">` on page load

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am using NGINX. I want to display the current time as an easy way of practicing. I set this in a JavaScript variable. So far, I have a little bit of HTML code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>???</title>
    <style>
      body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function myFunction() {
        var d = new Date()
        var n = d.getTime()

        document.getElementById('current-time').innerHTML = n
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="myFunction">
    <h1>???</h1>
    <p>This is the current time.</p>
    <p>
      <u>
        <i>
          Current Date and Time is
          <span id="current-time"></span>
        </i>
      </u>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don’t understand why this isn’t working, I have looked in Stack Overflow a lot and this is what they say to do. There are no errors printing in the console, and all the page says is “Current Date and Time is”, and nothing happens with the `<span id="current-time">`.

Comment: `onload='myFunction'` does nothing. _“I have looked in Stack Overflow a lot and this is what they say to do”_ — where have you seen `onclick='myFunction'` being recommended? Inline event handlers like `onclick` or `onload` are [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.

Comment: Ok, thanks I will look into that. Will that fix my issue??

Comment: Even better, either move the `<script>` to the bottom of the `<body>` element (your current HTML is [invalid](https://html5.validator.nu/), by the way), or replace the function by a `DOMContentLoadedListener`. See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/4642212) for these recommendations.

Comment: Probably, you should look at `window.addEventListener(‘DOMContentLoaded’, myFunction)`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon So vues `@click` or Reacts `onClick` then must be obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive way of registering events?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I’m not talking about Vue or React. I’m talking about the Level 0 DOM event model.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica Replace both `‘` and `’` by `"`, `'`, or `\``.

Comment: @BeginnerPythonLearner See [`window.onload` vs `<body onload=""/>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/191157/4642212); there are several approaches to “fix” this, but do stick with best practices. Before this gets lost, I’ll ask again: you say _“I have looked in Stack Overflow a lot and this is what they say to do”_ — Where, on Stack Overflow have you seen `onclick='myFunction'` being recommended?

Comment: @SebastianSimon: good catch, the joys of relying too heavily on iPad’s default quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Here: `<body onload="myFunction">` you just provided function reference without execution.

You will need to update it to be:
`<body onload="myFunction()">`

with `myFunction()` parentheses in the end, so your function will be actually executed on `onload` event.

Also, from your snipped above, it looks like `</body></html>` closing tags are missing.

Comment: I just didn't show that part, good catch though.

Answer (score 1):

Make <body onload="myFunction" <body onload="myFunction()"

Answer (score 0):

```
let d = new Date();
  
let n = d.toLocaleString();
```

will format correctly
as well as updating the parenthesis in:

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```